# strange error when i import example

Tags: android, android-emulator

and thanks for your help

I download the example of android book `android 4 application develop`, now I import the project but i see i have in console this error

```
 [2012-07-31 12:07:13 - PA4AD_Ch09_MyService] Unable to resolve target 'android-15'
```

and in the all class i have this:

```
 `import android.app.Activity; // for all import pachage`
```

I have this error:  The import android cannot be resolved
I see this error for all import package

if i create a new project all work well.
when i used android sdk tool 15 all work well, now i don't know to do, can you help me?

best regads

Antonio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to **Window** menu -> **preferance** -> select **Android** --> check **SDK location**

Comment: I do it but don't change nothing,

Comment: i fix the problem the problem :)  i click on  package where i have the first error and i select the configure build path, i select android lather i select the api level(i use api level 10)